# Why does function "checkpassword" makes nothing on click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem guys. As a beginner, I am trying to check the length of password and return the result, but it doesn't work. after clicking button, it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
function checkpassword(){
    var pas=document.getElementByName(passcode).value;
    var x=pas.length;
    if(x<8){
        document.getElementById(message).innerHTML="Error 404!";
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById(message).innerHTML="It's acceptable"
   }
}
</script>
<body>
   
    <input type="password" name="passcode" placeholder="Enter password to check">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="checkpassword()">

<p id="message"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to pass a string into `getElementBy*`

Comment: ^ -> `document.getElementByName('passcode')`

Comment: @DanielA.White                                                                                                   
 function checkpassword(){
    var pas=document.getElementByName(passcode);
    var n=toString(pas);
    var x=n.length();
    if(x<8){
        document.getElementById(message).innerHTML="Error 404!";
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById(message).innerHTML="It's acceptable"
   }
}                                                                                                                                            it still does nothing, I am going crazy

Comment: element names are not required to be unique; I think you would want `document.getElementsByName(...)[0];` or add an id attribute to the password element and use `document.getElementById("passcode");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@'Felix Kling' and @'Daniel A. White have given some hints in the comments because you will have to pass the names and ids as strings. But another issue is that `.getElementByName()` is not a function. You can try this (note that I have used `.getElementsByName` (plural) and referenced the zero-ith index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
function checkpassword(){
    var pas=document.getElementsByName('passcode')[0].value;
    var x=pas.length;
    if(x<8){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Error 404!";
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="It's acceptable"
   }
}
</script>
<body>
   
    <input type="password" name="passcode" placeholder="Enter password to check">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="checkpassword()">

<p id="message"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would you mind to tell me what does [0] do and why code doesn't work without it? @sog

Comment: The `.getElementsByName()` function will return an array of elements with the same name. The `[0]` indicates that you want the first element from this array. Since in your case, there is only one element then the passcode element is always in the first index of the array. If you were to add another element with the name attribute = "passcode" and place this new element BEFORE the passcode input in your body then the code would no longer work because the `[0]` indicates the first index of the array.

Comment: Another option you could try is to give the passcode element an id instead of a name and the use the `.getElementById()` which will only return a single element with the matching id attribute. But whichever option you choose depends on what you plan to do with the elements on the page. Some people may tell you that one way is better than another, but everything is always relative to what you plan to accomplish.

Comment: Everything understandable, thanks @sog